# Difference between a signatory and a member of the Cape Town Convention on International Interests in Mobile Equipment

Tags: international, treaty

Cape Town Convention on International Interests in Mobile Equipment is an international treaty intended to standardize transactions involving movable property. However, I see that Chile only signed the treaty and is not a member of the treaty. How are countries that signed it treated differently than the countries that are a member of it? I am trying to understand why some countries would choose to sign it rather than become a member of it.